# Test ansible playbook using rpm-based distros with systemd as Docker containers

Tags: travis-ci, ansible

I am writing ansible playbook for the Ansible.Galaxy that will [install nginx](https://github.com/weldpua2008/ansible-nginx) on any Linux distros.
But I felt to test it with Travis CI and Docker on images that include Systemd. Because SystemD gives an error:

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.

As you can see https://travis-ci.org/weldpua2008/ansible-nginx/jobs/78864352
There were errors.

So I try to represent it:

```
~# git clone https://github.com/weldpua2008/ansible-nginx.git
~# cd ansible-nginx
~# docker run -ti --rm=true  -v `pwd`:/ansible-nginx:rw centos:7 /bin/bash ^C
~# cd ansible-nginx/
~/ansible-nginx# docker run -ti --rm=true  -v `pwd`:/ansible-nginx:rw centos:7 /bin/bash

[root@2f6955a46b42 /]# /ansible-nginx/tests/test-on-rpm.sh
TASK: [ansible-nginx | create document root directory if needed] **************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [ansible-nginx | Starting nginx service] ********************************
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: no service or tool found for: nginx

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/test.retry

localhost                  : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Maybe there isn't this service?

```
[root@2f6955a46b42 /]#  systemctl enable nginx.service
[root@2f6955a46b42 /]#  systemctl -t service -a
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.
[root@2f6955a46b42 /]# chkconfig --list

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.
```

It's how I try to start service in ansible: https://github.com/weldpua2008/ansible-nginx/blob/master/tasks/main-centos.yml#L24

```
- name: Starting nginx service
  service: name=nginx state=started
  tags:
    - nginx
```

I tied to solve with https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7459

Comment: In your Centos 6 playbook, it looks like the nginx restart fails because the port is already in use (https://travis-ci.org/weldpua2008/ansible-nginx/jobs/78864352#L3972) - perhaps nginx needs restarting in a different way, or is already running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that Docker (normal "unprivileged") containers don't have the permissions to run `systemd` (as it wants access to the `/sys/fs/cgroup` filesystem).

But this is really because Docker containers prefer to run one process, the process you are trying to use them for - think of them as "a Unix process with a bunch of supporting utilities", rather than as "mini-VMs".

You need a simple Dockerfile inheriting from the Centos one, which installs `nginx` and then has a final `CMD` as something like:

```
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

For tips, here's the official `nginx` Dockerfile https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/7f3ef0927ec619d20181e677c97f991df0d7d446/Dockerfile

Comment: I try to test that ansible playbook will install nginx on the bare metal server or inside VM.

Comment: I can see that's the purpose of your repo, to write and test an Ansible script (which looks all good :), but the fact that TravisCI runs the tests in Docker containers means you're restricted to what works in them.

Comment: I tested Ansible on different Ubuntu versions but on CentOs 7 it fails to restart service: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/593#issuecomment-138809881

Comment: Yes, after reading that issue it seems the problem is with Ansible not detecting `systemd` correctly when running in a Docker container. Maybe changing the way you run the test on TravisCI might help? Not using Docker perhaps?

Comment: TravisCI uses Ubuntu-based images.  PS: Maybe there is another way to test on TravisCI  - vagrant?

Comment: I'm just testing running the CentOS 7 Docker image in `privileged` mode to see if that fixes it.